# Calloc simple problem

Tags: null, calloc

```
char* lw;
if((lw=(char *)calloc(2, sizeof(char))==0)) 
   printf("Failed to allocate.\n"); 
else 
   printf("allocated %p\n", lw);
```

I've read manual for calloc, need a quick and brief answer, why does it output NIL?
It goes to else, so lw cannot possibly be NIL, then outputs "allocated (nil)"? God's hand? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are assigning to lw `calloc(...) == 0`, which is `false`. You want it the other way around

Replace `==0))` with `)==NULL)`.